# Cakephp search feature

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I've to create search in my table externalclient
I tried this code in externalclientController.php

```
public function search()
    {
        //performs the search

        //tells this method to use the index.ctp View to display the results
        //rather than looking for search.ctp
        $this->view = 'index';
    }
```

---

and I create search.ctp

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('first_name',['action' => 'search']);
?>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td>Select Client</td>
<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter Client Name</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<?php echo $this->Form->select('first_name', $externalClient,['empty' => ' ',
'label'=>'']); ?>
</td>
<td><?php echo $this->Form->input('name', ['label' =>'']); ?></td>
<td>
<?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Search Client', true),
['name' => 'Search', 'div' => false]);?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

---

And the last thing I have added to my index.ctp

```
<?= $this->Html->link(__('Search'), ['action' => 'search',$externalClient->first_name]) ?>
```

...
After that it gives me this error:

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkmSx.png)

Comment: Your page cannot access externalClients variable. Can you show us what variables are set in cakephp debug kit?

Comment: Sorry I'm still learner and I don't get what do you mean by "cakephp debug kit"? do you mean codes in externalclientController.php?

Comment: I got what do you mean,

Comment: I got what do you mean and this is the debug informations.
Here you go this is a screen shot of the error in debugKit.
[url=http://postimg.org/image/jw27otc3d/][img=http://s12.postimg.org/jw27otc3d/Screen_Shot_2015_11_07_at_1_42_48_AM.jpg][/url]